# Alternative of savetree package

Tags: setspace, savetrees

The package savetree, causes conflicts and problems with many other packages. Is there any alternative of this package to save space.

Comment: Perhaps `fullpage` will be enough. One can also just use `geometry` to set small margins and either `titlesec` or `sectsty` to control space around section headings.